# how to define entity/model for these tables?

Tags: entity-framework

Table Student, columns:

```
id int primary key,
name varchar(20) not null
```

Table Class, columns:

```
id int primary key,
name varchar(20) not null
```

Student and class are many-to-many, so we have table StudentClass， in this table, we will know which classes does a student take, and which students in one class.

```
StudentId int FK,
ClassId int FK,
```

Next, table StudentClassProperty(use this table to store extra properties, these properties not belongs to student and not belongs to class, they belongs to class+student ), columns:

```
StudentId,
ClassId
Name,
Value,
```

table Course

```
id,
name
```

and table StudentClassCourse (different classes, has different courses, but all courses are optional )

```
StudentId,
ClassId,
CourseId
```

As far as I know, models can be:

```
class Student 
{
 int Id,
 string Name,

 ICollection Classes,
}

class Class
{
 int Id,
string name,

 ICollection Students,
}

class Course
{
 int Id,
string Name
}

in DbContext class, defines the many-to-many relationship for Class and Student

_db.Entry(
  .HasMany(a => a.Classes)
  .WithMany(b => b.Students)
  .Map (m => m.MapLeftKey("StudentId").MapRightKey("ClassId").ToTable("StudentClass"));
```

but how to define relationship for table StudentCLassPropery and StudentClassCourse? I want to use entities like this:

```
foreach(Student s in _db.Students)
{
  foreach(Class c in s.Classes)
  {
    foreach(Course course in c.Coures)
    {
      // ....
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do understand **NOTHING**. Are you sure that you didn't mess up all the letters A,B,C,D,...? What is the relationship between C and D? Is it many-to-many? But why is there a join table called TableABD instead of TableCD? Or isn't that a join table?

Comment: @Slauma I revised the question by concrete objects. hope you can understand all my question now.

Comment: Do you need to separate `StudentClass` and `StudentClassProperty` into two tables? It might be easier to have one table (basically remove the `StudentClass` table) and expose `StudentClassProperty` as an entity and create two one-to-many relationships between `Student` and `StudentClassProperty` and between `Class` and `StudentClassProperty` instead of a many-to-many relationship. But I don't understand the table `StudentClassCourse`. What are the primary keys and FK relationships in this table?

Comment: @Slauma Let me give you a sample for usage of table StudentClassCourse.  a student can take many classes(e.g. math, art), different classes has different courses(e.g. math has basic, adv, art has basic and adv), and student can choose different courses(e.g. Jim take Math class with adv course and take Art class with basic course). then we need a table to describe relationship between Student/Class/Course.

Comment: @Slauma Can't merge table StudentClass and StudentClassProperty, because StudentClassProperty is record extra infomation, the data in this table is optional.  StudentClass can describe relationship between Student and Class more directly...

Comment: @Slauma  I simplified SQL tables by surrogate keys. Then easy to write models ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/02/01/composite-keys-are-evil/

spirited by above link,  use surrogate keys to replace composite keys. than everything becomes quick easier.